# Collision Control for entries?

Tags: ee2, channel-entries, database

I am wondering if there is some sort of "data collision control" system available for EE. I am talking about a warning if a dataset is (about) being changed by two (or more users) at the same time, resulting in a potential dataloss.

EllisLab itself claims that EE is "a true content management system" and has an extensive User and Member Management Module. Even more I am baffled that this is not a core functionalty apparently. In the days of EE 1.x at least there was "Currently logged in Users" info near the footer of the CP.

There is an Extension "[Lock Entry](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/lock-entry)" on devotee but it looks like it is abandoned and the last time I tried it it seemed buggy.

Has anybody an idea on how to achieve this or how to maybe continue the work on Lock Entry?

Thanks and Cheers!

Comment: To circumvent this our team started using a GIT repo on our networked server (as we should've been doing from the beginning). However, I am not aware of any shared-versioning  add-on for EE. We started here: http://blog.smitec.net/posts/setting-up-a-git-server-on-osx/

Comment: Maybe I am missundstanding your approach or I didn't make my point clear enough: We are using GIT when working on code. In this case though I am looking for a way to "lock" an entry (e.g. a product) from a given channel to be edited by more than one user in the CP. Once you go to Lock Entry on devot-ee there will be a screenshot which shows exactly what I am looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, EE is missing a native workflow module. This is what it is. Thankfully, there is a robust developer community that stepped in and created options. I'd say your best bet is to get one of these working to protect the integrity of your data. Here are three in no particular order:

**Better Workflow**
http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/better-workflow

**Publisher**
http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/publisher

**NSM Publish Plus: Workflow**
http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/nsm-publish-plus-workflow

---

You might also check out **Edit Alarm** (http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/edit-alarm). It doesn't lock the entry but displays a message in the CP for a set amount of time after someone has started editing an entry. I used this on an EE1 site which had 8+ editors and it worked well. Haven't used it on an EE2 site.

Comment: Well, thanks Anna. I should have better pointed out that I do know about the Workflow Modules. But actually they add up too much overhead for us at the moment. I implemented a Draft Preview Function with the help of Stash and all we really need are the default Statuses. So not really a need for all the blows and whistles of Workflow Modules. I was just looking for a leightweighted small Extension, just like Lock Entry. So Edit-Alarm comes close, looks abandoned though also. :(